# What is the current draw during load on the LM1117 3.3v

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

I am looking at using the [LM1117 3.3v voltage regulator.](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM1117MPX-33-NOPB?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduhe0GGYFlBRuOtC02ANkOIp%2FqkXRk51T6Evr4hrwlVzFQ==)

I would like to determine the current draw to power the regulator's function, during output of something near 650mA.

All I can find is entries such as :

```
Quiescent current: 10mA
```

Is that my draw figure? Is there a better way to calculate it. As far as I understood, quiescent current was the draw under zero load. If this is the case, will this chip draw more current to output a higher 3.3v current? If yes, how do we know how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If this is the case, will this chip draw more current to output a higher 3.3v current? If yes, how do we know how much?

Yes, it will draw as much current from its input as it is providing to its output, plus the quiescent current.

So if it's providing  650 mA to the load, it will be drawing 660 mA from the input.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Regulators just draw the load current + no load (Q) current. (That's it)

To choose the right one'

- You need to know the Max & Min Voltage drop ΔV(in-out) specs at your current range roughly.
- the thermal rise,ΔTj

  - rise of junction = \$ΔTj=Pd*R_{\Theta JA}\$ **for Tj=85'C max** for good MTBF or less for cooler preference to minimize effects on Analog drift of other parts.
  - **Pd = ΔV * ΔI**  (choose the max product)
  - Choose a package with adequate size and board heatsink. e.g.if Rja=62'C/W and (5V-3.3V)*0.65A=1.1W , ΔTj=69'C above ambient. which exceeds what a hot CPU  runs at  25'C ambient.